# Security of IBE schemes

Tags: cr.crypto-security

Suppose we have an [ID-based encryption (IBE)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID-based_encryption) (Setup, Extract, Enc, Dec) scheme which is [IND-ID-CPA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ciphertext_indistinguishability#Indistinguishability_under_chosen-plaintext_attack_.28IND-CPA.29) (resp [IND-ID-CCA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ciphertext_indistinguishability#Indistinguishability_under_chosen_ciphertext_attack.2Fadaptive_chosen_ciphertext_attack_.28IND-CCA.2C_IND-CCA2.29)) secure, and we want to construct [threshold version](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threshold_cryptosystem) of this scheme.
My question is: how to define the IND-ID-XXX security game for the new scheme.

Comment: Please note that not all people here are experts in cryptography, while many are willing to help. If you describe the jargon or provide the links, you probably get an answer much faster. I added some links, but you'd better add some descriptions as well.

Comment: And, by the way, have you seen this http://www.iacr.org/archive/pkc2004/29470260/29470260.pdf?

Comment: Why would the situation be fundamentally different from the case of standard threshold encryption?